# Binary Search Tree insert method (map interface)

Tags: java, binary-search, tree

This is my implementation based on `Map<K,V>` interface. The BST is a linked binary tree with root reference, both internal and external nodes (`MyBSNode`) contains **(key, value)** entries

What do you think? There's something to improve?

```
public BSPosition<E> insert(int k, E e) {
    if(isEmpty()){
        /* Sets root */
        BSPosition<E> r = new MyBSNode<E>(null);
        r.setElement(k, e);
        setRoot(r);
        size++;
        return r;
    }

    BSPosition<E> n = treeInsert(k, root);          //k-key node or last node visited
    if(k == n.getKey()){                            //tree has already a k-key node
        n.setElement(k, e);                         //only modifies e
        return n;           
    }
    /* n is a external (last visited) node with different key */
    size++;
    if(k < n.getKey())
        return n.setLeftChild(k, e);
    else 
        return n.setRightChild(k, e);

}

private BSPosition<E> treeInsert(int k, BSPosition<E> v){
    if(isLeaf(v))                       return v;           

    if(k < v.getKey()){
        if(v.getLeftChild() == null)    return v;
        return treeInsert(k, v.getLeftChild());
    }
    else if(k == v.getKey())            return v;

    else{
        if(v.getRightChild() == null)   return v;
        return treeInsert(k, v.getRightChild());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm looks fine. Some other notes:

1. I would use longer variable names than `r`, `k`, `e` etc. Longer names would make the code more readable since readers/maintainers don't have to decode or memorize the abbreviations.
2. ```
   new MyBSNode<E>(null)
   ```

   Consider creating a default contructor, a named factory method or an explanatory local variable for `null`. Currently readers have to check the `MyBSNode` constructor to figure out what's that null supposed to mean.
3. `MyBSNode` does not seem to have a good name. Try to find something more descriptive.
4. ```
   n.setElement(k, e); // only modifies e
   ```

   Creating a `setValue(E value)` method would make the comment unnecessary and would be cleaner.
5. I'd consider moving `isLeaf` to `BSPosition` since it seems [data envy](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DataEnvy). I guess its only task is to check that both left and right children are `null`s.
6. `treeInsert` does not do any insertion, its name is a little bit misleading, it just searches the parent of the new node or a node with the same key. I'd call it according to that. (`searchInsertionPoint` for example.)